# New-PSDrive gives password error from one -Root path, but is fine for another

Tags: powershell, new-psdrive

I have the following script:

```
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$DeployLocation" -Credential $credentials
New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$autobuildSourceFiles" -Credential $credentials
```

When this runs, the first drive maps correctly, but the second one fails with the following error:

> InvalidOperation: The specified network password is not correct

This is really a confusing error, because I pass in the exact same `$credentials` object for both calls.  If one of them works, then I do not see how the password can be incorrect.

In case it is relevant, the variables look like this:

```
$DeployLocation = "\\dev-server\DevFiles\Technical\MyProjectNameHere"
$autobuildSourceFiles = "\\mainshare\build`$\Technical\MyProjectNameHere\1.0.0.94"
```

The user in the `$credentials` variable has read and write permissions to `$DeployLocation` and read-only permissiosn to `$autobuildSourceFiles`.  But I don't see how that would cause a password error.

Things I have tried:

- Swapping the order of the calls (to ensure that there is not an issue with making more than one `PSDrive`).  When I swap the order, the same one (drive "K") fails.
- Changing the drive letter. (I tried "Y" as well)
- Using the exact same text for the command that does work, but substituting the path that does not.  (It still failed).

Note: I am using Powershell Version 5.1.14393.5127 on Windows.

**What could be causing this error, and how can I work around it?**

Comment: Are both shares in the same server or different servers? Is the `$credentials` local or AD?

Comment: For remote computers to recognize a credential they must be in the same group and use the same password server(s).   A network drive is mounted on a Server and to mount a drive you need the server to recognize the credentials and you have to have permission on the server to access the drive/folder

Comment: $autobuildSourceFiles value includes `$`, which has special meaning in PowerShell. You have to replace `"` with `'`. I.e. `$autobuildSourceFiles = '\\mainshare\build$\Technical\MyProjectNameHere\1.0.0.94'`, instead of `$autobuildSourceFiles = "\\mainshare\build$\Technical\MyProjectNameHere\1.0.0.94"`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Different servers.  The `$credentials` are AD creds.

Comment: @MikeSh - Yeah, I did that in my actual code.  When I put it in the question, I was copy/pasting in actual values so I lost the back tick.  I will update the question with the back tick.

Comment: @Vaccano, have you tried my suggestion? I.e. 'aaa$bbb' instead of "aaa`$bbb"?

Comment: @MikeSh - Yes.  Sadly I got the same error.